# Dynamic Links in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create dynamic links in my flutter application such that I can have a link like this: `project.com/user/<userid>`, and retrieve data using the `userid`. How do you do this in flutter?

Comment: https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments

Answer (score 0):

**First Method**

```
String dynamicLink = "project.com/user/33989";
  String userID = dynamicLink.split("/").last;
  print("Userid is $userID");
```

**Second Method:- Create Function for get user id using Link.**

```
String dynamicLink = "project.com/user/33989";
String getUserid({required String link}){
    print("Link: $link");
    print("Userid: ${link.split("/").last}");
    return link.split("/").last; 
  }
  print("Userid using function ${getUserid(link: dynamicLink)}");
```